# Struts2 and BlazeDS on Spring3

Tags: spring, struts2, flex4, blazeds

I would like to configure settings both blazeds and Struts2 running on springframework at the same time.
I configured web.xml like below. But one works another doesn't work. 
Becaouse Struts2 filters AMF protocol.

If I comment out one of them, It works property. vice versa.

Is there any way to configure struts2 settings to work both?

---

web.xml

```
<!-- Struts2 Settings  
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>struts.devMode</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
-->

    <!-- Flex Settings -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>flex.messaging.HttpFlexSession</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- MessageBroker Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>MessageBrokerServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services.configuration.file</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

---

**For Devlopment**

JDK1.6

Spring3.0.1

Tomcat6.0

Flex4.6

Comment: Have you tried changing the url pattern.

Comment: I'm so sorry. Not yet. I will reply in 3 days. I'm swallowed up by another emergency task right now. It sucks.

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude some patterns from Struts2 filter. Define `struts.action.excludePattern` constant in your `struts.xml` file.

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value=".*unfiltered.*,.*\\.nofilter"/>
```